# No title bar in qpdfview

Tags: linux

I have qpdfview installed on linuxmint 18.The app doesn't show titlebar and is always in fullscreen(f11) mode.there is no max/minnimize or close buttons nor the taskbar.I am not able to have a floating window.

The reason this happened was once I pressed and holded the f11 button for a few seconds and then from then the titlebar was gone.

I uninstalled the software cleaned the directories then reinsatlled a few times but still the same result.
[Image of the qpdfview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCHId.png)

Then I observed this unusual output for wmctrl -l command
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPlq8.png)

Answer (score 0):

If this issue is related to qpdfview, try to check the local configuration [file](https://manned.org/qpdfview/a96fd195):

> qpdfview uses a configuration file usually located at
>                 "~/.config/qpdfview/qpdfview.conf",
>          which allows configuration of the toolbars and thumbnails.
>   look for something that uses fullscreen or no borders

If this is not working or its system wide, check  the compositing options of your desktop [environment](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/mint-mate-first)

> 2.8. You can improve graphical performance of your Linux Mint Mate like this:
>   Menu button - Preferences - Windows
>   Deselect: Enable software compositing window manager